# Using a function as a parameter to another function in Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, methods, python-idle

I'm working on a simple idea just to get a better grip on Python. I'm having trouble though.

Here's my code:

```
def backToMain(f):
    print('Back to Main Menu (B)')
    back = input('>>>')
    back = back.lower()
    if back == 'b':
        mainMenu()
    else:
        print('\nThat is not a valid input.\n\n')
        f

def instruct():
    instructtxt= str('INSTRUCTIONS')
    instructlen = len(instructtxt) * 6
    print(instructtxt.center(instructlen,'~'))
    backToMain(instruct())
```

What I'm trying to get to happen is so that everytime the user isn't on the Main Menu (i.e instructions, credits, etc.) they are prompted with a text at the bottom, "Back to Main Menu" and if the 'b' key is pressed, they are brought back into the mainMenu() function. If not, they are told it is not a valid input and brought back to the beginning of the function they are currently in.

The problem is though, since I want the backToMain() function in multiple *other* functions, that when the user enters anything but 'b' in the prompt they will be brought to the beginning of the function they're attempting to exit. What currently happens though is that once you enter the instruct()'s print statement just repeats itself to infinite.

Anyone think they could help me out? If I wasn't clear, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: Thanks for that @BrenBarn, it's fixed. Although, the code is properly indented in the actual script so, the indentation wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using parentheses in the wrong place.  When you write `instruct()`, you call `instruct()`.  When you call a function, its arguments are evaluated before it is called.  So when you do `backToMain(instruct())`, it has to call `instruct()` in order to pass its return value as an argument, which means it calls `instruct` again, which calls it again, etc.

To pass the function itself (not its return value), do `backToMain(instruct)`.

In `backToMain` you have the opposite problem.  At the end you need to do `f()`.  `f` by itself is just a reference to the function, not a call, and so it won't do anything.  To call a function you need to use parentheses; to pass the function object you need to not use parentheses.

That said, this is a not a great way to do this.  It creates many recursive calls.  If the user puts in a lot of invalid input, he may hit the recursion limit.  It's hard to say how better to do it without knowing more about the overall structure of your program, but in general it's better to avoid recursion as a technique for just "starting over"; you should prefer a loop for that.

Comment: Thank you, this is was exactly the issue. Now, forgive the ignorance, but how would this technique create recursive calls? Furthermore, would something as simple as sticking the current code in a while loop fix this issue?

Comment: @ryanhagz: Suppose you call `instruct`.  Then it calls `backToMain`.  If the user enters invalid input, `instruct` will be called again.  This is a recursive call (albeit indirect).  Also, if the user makes some choices from `mainMenu` and then somehow makes his way to `backToMain` and hits b, `mainMenu` will be called again (recursively).  Basically, every time the user does something, you are re-calling the associated function instead of returning to the invocation of it that was already called.